# Просмотр описания стандартных классов Java

Tags: java, классы, intellij-idea

Как можно посмотреть описания стандартных классов, например, `Integer` или `String` через Intellij idea?

Comment: Что значит `описание`? Возможно, `ctrl+b` по названию класса поможет.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Определение чего-угодно в IDEA можно посмотреть, зажав <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> и нажав левой клавишей мыши на название объекта или класса. В случае, если IDE имеет в наличии исходники класса - она покажет нужное место в них. Если же исходников нет, а код ссылается на скомпилированную зависимость - IDEA произведет декомпиляцию class файла и покажет результат

Answer (score 3):

Да, можно. Наведите мышь на имя класса и нажмите

- для винды <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ЛКМ</kbd>
- для мака <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>ЛКМ</kbd>

где <kbd>ЛКМ</kbd> - Левая Клавиша Мыши